# How to fetch data from Spring boot in react native?

Tags: spring-boot, fetch, react-native, expo

I have a frontend created with react native expo and my backend is done using spring boot and the model is in google cloud when I run the spring boot locally and type the URL in the browser (without deploying 'localhost URL' )it displays the data on the browser. How can I get that data to my react native application without deploying the google cloud.

```
 componentDidMount() {
     fetch('http://192.168.56.1:8080/users/toFrontend?email=meNewTwo@gmail.com')
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((json) => {
         this.setState({ data: json});
     })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
     .finally(() => {
       this.setState({ isLoading: false });
     });
```

This is the code I used

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('http://{your IP}:8081/')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({ message : responseJson.message.data })
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Now that we have **Command Prompt** lets type `ipconfig` press enter and grab the number under IPv4 Address. This number is your local IP.

**REST API**

```
fetch('http://{your IP}:8081/',{
          method: 'GET',// denpends upon your call POST or GET
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

       console.log(responseJson);

    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Here is the official [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network)

Comment: It doesn't work it gives a network error as 'Network Request Failed', it is as follows
xhr.onerror
C:\Users\ratna\Downloads\New folder (9)\MealizeProject\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:473:29

Comment: I added the code to the question now the spring boot URL is as localhost:8080 and the database is on google cloud so I used my public IP

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys finally fixed it there was a return missing in the code

```
 fetch('URL')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
   })
  .then((responseData => {
    console.log(responseData);
   this.setState({ data: responseData });
     }))
```

The localhost part of the URL is the IPv4, the local Ip and  variable is data:[ ]